# How to right align a bootstrap modal that takes up half of the screen for devices medium and up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a modal that is triggered by a button. I would like the modal to be width: 50vw; and height: 100vh; (take up half of the screen). I would like the menu to be fixed on the right for devices medium and up and to take up the whole screen for screens medium and below. I have the following code so far, but I am not sure how to style this with CSS:

```css
.icon-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: black;
}

#modal-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 721px;
  height: 900px;
  left: 930px;
  top: -76px;
  margin-left: -225px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="icon-button bg-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
          </button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" id="modal-nav">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Interiores Comerciais</h2>
        <h2>Interiores Residenciais</h2>
        <h2>Arquitetura Residencial</h2>
        <h2>Arquitetura Comercial</h2>
        <h2>Inspirações</h2>
        <h2>Quem Somos</h2>
        <h2>Contato</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also added the Codepen which may be a bit easier to see:
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/jrod95/pen/wveBKyw)

Comment: Have you tried using a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) ?

Comment: Not yet, since at first I just wanted the half-screen modal to work before moving to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `media query` to achieve that.
And width and height need to be changed for **.modal-dialog** not **.modal-content**

```css
.icon-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: black;
}

#modal-nav {
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#modal-nav .modal-content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.modal {
  padding: 0!important;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #modal-nav {
    max-width: 50vw!important;
    margin-left:auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="icon-button bg-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
          </button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="modal-nav">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Interiores Comerciais</h2>
        <h2>Interiores Residenciais</h2>
        <h2>Arquitetura Residencial</h2>
        <h2>Arquitetura Comercial</h2>
        <h2>Inspirações</h2>
        <h2>Quem Somos</h2>
        <h2>Contato</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Amal! I will try to move it to the right now, but this makes a lot of sense. I was really struggling there...

Comment: I have made it to right so now u can confirm my answer